# How to draw a partial or incomplete box around one or more words within a paragraph

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, fancybox

I am trying to draw a partial box around one or more words within a paragraph--that is, a rectangle with one or more sides missing. I have read the documentation for the `fancybox` package and it doesn't seem to be able to do what I want. I was able to produce thus ugly hack:

[image]

That's just a vertical bar | followed by a word with \overline and \uline. The trick is to connect the vertical and horizontal lines so that you have a rectangle missing just one side.

Is there an easy, general way to do this, perhaps with Tikz? I don't know enough about that package to be able to do this myself, but I'm wondering if there might be other solutions too.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with your partial solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solution EDITED to allow multiple sides to be stricken.

Made into a macro `\partbox{<sides>}{<content>}` where `sides` are the sides to be stricken, in any combination (in any order) of `l`, `b`, `r`, or `t`.  By using `\fbox`, it is customizeable with the use of `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.

Being a box, the words if more than one, will not be permitted to break across a line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\newif\iflclip
\newif\ifbclip
\newif\ifrclip
\newif\iftclip
\def\CLIP{\dimexpr\fboxrule+.2pt\relax}
\def\nulclip{0pt}
\newcommand\partbox[2]{%
  \lclipfalse\bclipfalse\rclipfalse\tclipfalse%
  \let\lkern\relax\let\rkern\relax%
  \let\lclip\nulclip\let\bclip\nulclip\let\rclip\nulclip\let\tclip\nulclip%
  \parseclip#1\relax\relax%
  \iflclip\def\lkern{\kern\CLIP}\def\lclip{\CLIP}\fi
  \ifbclip\def\bclip{\CLIP}\fi
  \ifrclip\def\rkern{\kern\CLIP}\def\rclip{\CLIP}\fi
  \iftclip\def\tclip{\CLIP}\fi
  \lkern\clipbox{\lclip{} \bclip{} \rclip{} \tclip}{\fbox{#2}}\rkern%
}
\def\parseclip#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx l#1\lcliptrue\else
  \ifx b#1\bcliptrue\else
  \ifx r#1\rcliptrue\else
  \ifx t#1\tcliptrue\else
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\parseclip#2\relax\fi
}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\partbox{l}{dans} \partbox{b}{dans} \partbox{r}{dans} \partbox{t}{dans}

\partbox{lt}{dans} \partbox{lr}{dans} \partbox{lb}{dans}

\partbox{tb}{dans} \partbox{tr}{dans}

\partbox{br}{dans}

\partbox{rlt}{dans} \partbox{rbt}{dans} \partbox{blt}{dans} \partbox{blr}{dans}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to show the ability to use `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`, here is the identical result, but with `\fboxsep=0pt\relax\fboxrule=1pt\relax` set at the beginning of the document:

[image]

If one wishes it not to interfere with linespacing, then this tweak should work, adding a `\vphantom` and `\smash`.  Of course, it will not prevent overlap, if `\fboxsep` and/or `\fboxrule` are set large enough (NOTE: this solution is still the original variety, only allowing a single side to be stricken):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\def\CLIP{\dimexpr\fboxrule+.2pt\relax}
\newcommand\partbox[2]{\leavevmode\vphantom{#2}\smash{%
  \ifx#1l\clipbox{\CLIP{} 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\fbox{#2}}\else
  \ifx#1b\clipbox{0pt \CLIP{} 0pt 0pt}{\fbox{#2}}\else
  \ifx#1r\clipbox{0pt 0pt \CLIP{} 0pt}{\fbox{#2}}\else
  \ifx#1t\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt \CLIP{}}{\fbox{#2}}\else
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4] \partbox{l}{dans}
\lipsum[4] \partbox{b}{dans}
\lipsum[4] \partbox{r}{dans}
\lipsum[4] \partbox{t}{dans}
\lipsum[4] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder how does this look like in a paragraph, surrounded by running text.

Comment: @Matsmath It will behave like `\fbox`, subject to changes in `\fboxrule` and `\fboxsep`.

Comment: Beautiful solution. I wonder, is there any easy way to modify this code to remove two of the sides--say, the top and left, at one time?

Comment: @twoblackboxes Please see revision of 1st answer to see how it can be done.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is really excellent work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

> Is there an easy, general way to do this, perhaps with Tikz?

I cannot understand the tendency of people to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Perhaps with `tabular`?

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tabcolsep.2em
Un voyage \begin{tabular}{|c }\hline dans\\\hline \end{tabular} l'space. 
Un voyage \begin{tabular}{|c|}\hline dans\\       \end{tabular} l'space. 
Un voyage \begin{tabular}{ c|}\hline dans\\\hline \end{tabular} l'space. 
Un voyage \begin{tabular}{|c|}       dans\\\hline \end{tabular} l'space. 
\end{document}
```

If you hate `tabular`, some `\makebox`, `\rule` and `\vrule` commands can do the same work. However, it is tedious  finding  manually the right widths of the horizontal rules. But this is solved using `\widthof of`the `calc` package. This make a complete framed box with automatic width:

```
\vrule%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-.25em]{\widthof{dans}+.2em}{.4pt}}% 
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.85em]{\widthof{dans}+.2em}{.4pt}}%
\makebox[\widthof{dans}+.2em][c]{dans}%
\vrule\
```

Simply removing rows 1,2,3 or 5 in the above code you can obtain the incomplete boxes.

Convert both solutions in macros is straightforward. For simplicity, instead of a single macro with two arguments, I suggest make four macros where the text is the unique argument. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\openleftbox[1]{%
\vrule
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-.25em]{\widthof{#1}+.2em}{.4pt}}% 
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.85em]{\widthof{#1}+.2em}{.4pt}}%
\makebox[\widthof{#1}+.2em][c]{#1}%
%\vrule\ 
}
\begin{document}
Un voyage \openleftbox{dans} l'space. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sledgehammer?  If you go to my profile, you will see that "I enjoy... reinventing the wheel"  Perhaps I should add that I enjoy cracking nuts with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes [In this way?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCq1vkvvqAU)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `tcbox` (from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcbox{\lbox}[1][]{on line, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, size=small, leftrule=0pt,#1}

\newtcbox{\rbox}[1][]{on line, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, size=small, rightrule=0pt,#1}

\newtcbox{\tbox}[1][]{on line, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, size=small, toprule=0pt,#1}

\newtcbox{\bbox}[1][]{on line, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, size=small, bottomrule=0pt,#1}

\begin{document}

The \lbox{quick} \tbox{brown} \bbox{fox} \rbox{jumps} over the \lbox[colback=red!30, colframe=blue]{lazy dog}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the [`efbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/efbox) package.

Examples from the documentation:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{efbox}

\begin{document}

\efbox{Foo}
\efbox[rightline=false,topline=false]{Foo}
\efbox[topline,backgroundcolor=red]{Foo}
\efbox[linewidth=2pt,font=\Large]{Large Foo}
\efbox[rightline=false,topline=false,linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{Foo}
\efbox[margin=10pt,backgroundcolor=yellow,font=\ttfamily\itshape]{Italic Typewriter Foo}
\efbox[linewidth=3pt,margin=5pt,backgroundcolor=red]{Foo}
\efbox[hidealllines,backgroundcolor=red]{Foo}
\efbox{Foo}
\efbox[hidealllines,backgroundcolor=red,margin=15pt]{Foo}
\efbox[margin=15pt,linewidth=5pt]{Foo}
\efbox[bottomline=false,rightline=false,linewidth=2pt,margin=1pt,backgroundcolor=yellow]{Foo}
\efbox{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the easiest method presented here. However, I don't know why, but it is bugged. I managed to draw what i want after many experiments, adding backslashes in front etc..

Answer (score 1):

Package [`fbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fbox) has been recently added to CTAN. This package adds an optional parameter to `\fbox`. This new parameter allows to declare which box sides should be drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fbox}

\begin{document}

The \fbox[tb]{quick} \fbox[lr]{brown} \fbox[ltb]{fox} \fbox[trb]{jumps} \fbox[lb]{over} \fbox[tr]{the} \fbox{lazy dog}.

\end{document}
```

[image]