# Latex Symbol for the inverse (negative) angle of Complex Number?

Tags: symbols, texmaker, angle

Is there a Latex symbol to represent the inverse angle of a complex number? Since, from what i see, this isn't very well known, I'll post a picture of my math book which uses it below (Engineering Mathematics - Stroud). Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can use the information provided in [How to draw a partial or incomplete box around one or more words within a paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323986/5764) to create your own `\invangleb{120}` and `\invanglet{135}` (say).

Comment: How can a number have an inverse angle? (Off-topic, obviously.) Does 1 have an inverse angle, let alone *i*?

Comment: @cfr It's just the negative angle. Negative 135 = 360 -135 = 225.

Comment: I know what an inverse angle is. I just doubt that numbers can have them. I doubly doubt that complex numbers can.