# How do I apply partial borders around symbols?

Tags: symbols, border

I'm working on a project that requires me to write partial borders around individual symbols, like this:

[image]

I haven't been able to find any conclusive answers to how to do it, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: This question exists already, but I'm having difficulty locating it...

Comment: Found it!  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323986/how-to-draw-a-partial-or-incomplete-box-around-one-or-more-words-within-a-paragr

Comment: If you agree that the cited question is essentially identical, then we can close your question as a duplicate.  Is that so?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's pretty similar, yeah