# How can I define/draw a Gamma Function to write it as per this image

Tags: symbols

Want to define a function such that it draws gamma function as per this image[image: Gamma Function stretchable]

Comment: your image is not readable. Do you like to write this equation or draw Gamma function? From tag one can conclude, that you looking for symbol $\Gamma$ ... Clarify your question!

Comment: Do you mean something like [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwBHt.png)?

Comment: @egreg Wish you and your family a very happy New year...

Comment: I have never seen a `$\Gamma(1+p)$` where the “roof” of `\Gamma` extends to cover the argument. Could you please elaborate more about where your notation comes from (instead of just a photo)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to draw a partial or incomplete box around one or more words within a paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323986/5764)

Answer (score 3):

Does one of the following possible solutions meet your formatting needs?

[image]

I must confess to not knowing what these expressions may have in common with the (conventionally defined) gamma function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
% The following two macros must be used in math mode:
\newcommand\solutionA[1]{%
    \mathop{}\!\begin{array}[b]{|c}\hline #1 \end{array}}
\newcommand\solutionB[1]{%
   \mathop{}\!\begin{array}[b]{|@{\,}c@{\,}}\hline #1 \end{array}}
%% (The `\mathop{}\!` particles serve to insert a bit of whitespace, if needed.
%%  Many thanks to @egreg for providing this suggestion.)

\begin{document}
$\solutionA{1+p}$ $\solutionB{1+p}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `array` (with default optional argument `[c]`) approach will produce a different baseline for the `1+p` with respect to the surrounding material. See https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/147 Better to explicitly specify `[t]` or `[b]`. Since it is only one row, it should not matter.

Comment: @RuixiZhang - Many thanks. I've implemented your suggestion to use the `[b]` placement specifier for the `array` environments. Let's see if the OP weighs in with his/her opinion on whether my suggestions are even close to what is needed.

Comment: I'd consider adding `\mathop{}\!` in front of `\solutionB` (which is better than `\solutionA`).

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this suggestion. I've updated the macros `\solutionA` and `\solutionB` accordingly. I'm still hoping that the OP will weigh in and provide some more information about the mysterious desired format for the gamma function...

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. I have tried to do some editing in your formula but I am unable to add some whitespace between 1 (of 1/2) and the overline, I typed this $\solutionB{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @Anit - Does `$\solutionB{\frac{1\mathstrut}{2}}$` work for you? I.e., according to your preferences, does it provide enough whitespace between `1` and the horizontal line? If not, is `$\solutionB{\frac{1\strut}{2}}$` satisfactory?